# Plogit: Lasso logistic regression with Stata

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, lasso

I want to execute a Lasso logistic regression with Stata.

Why? Because...
 1.) I have a dummy dependant variable (=> Investment success (1) and failure (0)); samples(1/0)(28/23).
2.) I have a set of 63 possible predictors (all continuous).

Unfortunately, I have to do it with Stata and there is only one user written program called plogit for that.

The documentation of plogit is not very detailed and there are no examples online on how to execute it properly.

My questions are:

- When searching via plsearch for optimal lambda, what exactly do I have specify in lambda(#)?
- I was not able to stick more than 15 predictors into the plogit log. regression. Is it possible to put in all 63?
- Why do I often get error messages like:
  => “observation numbers out of  range” 
  => “convergence not achieved”

I know most of my questions aren't very detailed, so just ask if you need some further information.

Comment: These are question that are very specific to one package in one program. Your best chance will be to contact the author of that package directly.

Comment: Thx for the response Maarten, I already did that and now I received an answer. He recommended using R. I guess, I shlould try to use R from wihin Stata.